# using angular ng-style to call out a background image

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having an with using the `ng-style` directive. I want to create add a button to my `ng-repeat` which is css sprite. If i include the sprite normal way my element inspector has a good old moan. from the information i gather from the Angular [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/)

i thought it was as simple as the following:

```
<button ng-style="{'background-image':'url:('/img/Myimage.png')'}">test</button>
```

However i am receiving a snytax error message from this line of code. Does anyone know the correct method?

Comment: You probably need to escape the quotes in url as: `'url:(\'/img/Myimage.png\')'`

Comment: syntax for `url` is incorrect, should not be `:` after it and quotes on src not required...would remove in angular markup

Comment: @idbentley thanks i spotted where i have gone wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
<button ng-style="{'background-image':'url(\'img/MyImage.png\')'}">test</button>
```

is the correct way to do it. was missing the escape the quotes in url `'url:(\'/img/Myimage.png\')'`

Answer (score 0):

oh,`{color:' something',background:'something '}`

```
ng-style="{background:'url(something)'}"
```

or

```
ng-style="{'background-image':'url(something)'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS syntax is incorrect for `url`, you have extra `:` and I would remove quotes for the src so the whole property is one string

```
<button ng-style="{'background-image':'url(/img/Myimage.png)'}">test</button>
```

I really don't undertsand why you would use `ng-style` for this. A simple CSS rule and class would make more sense since you aren't evaluating anything

Comment: <button ng-style="{'background-image':'url(\'img/MyImage.png\')'}">test</button> actually work for me

Comment: what is point of using `ng-styl` in the first place for this?

Comment: Bcos my button is in an ng-repeat function. if i add this image to my css i get error messages inspector. It's for best practices

Comment: that makes no sense at all