# using angular ng-style on an image tag to call out a background image

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-style

I'm trying to conditionally display an image with ng-style.
I've tried all the suggestions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20176315/using-angular-ng-style-to-call-out-a-background-image) (and in the docs) but nothing seems to work.

```
    first try:
<br/>
<img alt="" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(\'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png\')'}">
<br/>
second try:    
<br/>
<img src="" alt="" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(\'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png\')'}">
<br/>
third try:    
<br/>
<img src="" alt="" ng-style="{background-image:'url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png)'}">
<br/>
fourth try:    
<br/>
<img src="" alt="" ng-style="{background:'url(https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png)'}">
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SEY9c/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background-image` doesn't make sense with the `<img>` element so you need to use `ng-src` instead of `ng-style`.

Also, you're missing the `ng-app` attribute in your example so Angular isn't actually running.

So a working example would be:

```
<div ng-app>
    <img ng-src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png">
</div>
```

Although, I guess you can use `ng-style` on other elements, like a `div`. Just make sure it has content in it so the background actually shows up:

```
<div ng-app>
    <div style="padding: 20px;" ng-style="{'background-image':'url(\'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo4w.png\')'}">This is some content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I also need to change some style properties as well (height,width, etc)? Seems like the solution is to use a div..

Comment: In that case it's fine, you can use the `ng-style` tag to set those sorts of properties. It just doesn't make sense to set `background-image` on an `<img>` element.